# Xamarin cross-platform visual studio bottom navigation

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform, visual-studio-2017

I just started using xamarin in visual studio for building cross-platform apps, and i was searching on the internet for some tutorial etc, and i ran into a website "material.io" and i found this amazing [bottom navigation](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#)

So i searched on google for a tutorial to make that bottom navigation in xamarin.forms cross-platform environment.

But i didn,'t find anything, so i hoped that someone here at stackoverflow knew how to or could provide me with code or a tutorial.

thanks in advance

Comment: this is the default behavior of a TabbedPage in iOS.  On Android, the default is to put tabs at the top, but you can customize this behavior with a custom renderer

Comment: thanks for the quick respons, but do you have any kind of guide of starting this TabbedPage?

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/tabbed-page/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jason already mentioned, something like this requires a custom renderer. However, you're lucky since someone has already done the hard work for you.

There's a Xamarin.Android control called [BottomNavigationBar](https://github.com/pocheshire/BottomNavigationBar) which has been ported to Xamarin.Forms in the project [BottomNavigationBarXF](https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF). You'll also find an example of how to get started on the latter repository. On iOS, the control defaults to the standard page with tabs on the bottom.

[image]